# How far away can DDR3 memory be placed from the SoC?

Tags: trace, socket, soc, ddr3, length-matching

I thought of an idea where i have a pcb with a soc on it, and a seperate one with the DDR3 memory that can snap into each other.
This way i can replace or debug specefic parts of the system and have e.g. a how swappable soc in my system.
So my question is:
What is the maximum distance i can place DDR3 chips away from the SoC(so it still works) when all traces are length matched between each other?(Using 2,4 and 6 layer boards?)

Thanks

Comment: The connector will be non-trivial. Use a standard DIMM and connector. Then read the documentation for those.

Comment: But don't desktop dimms use some other technique to mix all chips?Or is that not what you mean/am i wrong?

Comment: Do you mean "hot-swappable SoC"? How do you imagine that will work?

Comment: I mean having Ram, SoC(with power and such),storage, and io as a seperate board that connects to each other. This way i can design a new board with soc, without redesigning the ram,storage, and io part.

Comment: Normally called "system on module". Looks like TI make one but with the RAM attached. http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Sitara_AM335x_Boards#Emtrion.2CDIMM-AM335x_System_on_Module ; note that they are generally not *hot* swappable without special design of the processor.

Comment: They are not meant to be hot swapable, i'l just turn off everything. 
Well, i am designing something that has sort of the same design as a desktop, there is a cpu with socket, then there is ram, storage, io and such on motherboard.(only mine will have voltage regulators onboard)
And then I could design a new cpu(with power module onboard) without the need to replace everything.

Comment: I think you'll find most desktop motherboards have voltage regulators on board.

Comment: I am aware of that, but keeping them on the SoC board themself would simplify things for me a lot.